# how to reduce upgrade SSTable time in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-2.1

I recently upgraded my Cassandra cluster from `2.1.12` to `3.9`. And, it took 10-12 hours for each to upgrade the SStables total size of data was ~100GB on each node. Morever, `compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec` in my cluster was `16 as default value`. What are the ways by means of which this time could have been reduced?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SSDs? If you have extra IO bandwidth increasing compaction throughput (`compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec`) is the easiest. You can also increase the `concurrent_compactors` in your cassandra.yaml, but you will ultimately be limited by CPU and disk io.

Can also disable gossip/cql with nodetool on one node at a time to prevent it from impacting your application, then disable the compaction throughput all together. Just make sure to not have node removed from cluster for over 20 min (30 min is the default Hinted Handoff window).